# Dynamic JSON Formatting Issue

Tags: arrays, json

My application reads JSON data in a particular format. I am pulling data from a database to dynamically create the data. I have the data, I just do not know the proper way to put it all in the following format.

Note: the first 2 sets are pulled from one query, and the "variables" section is what needs to be looped through to populate as the variable names AND values are in their own fields.

```
Sample Tables<br>
```

Master Table
ID | Custom_Col1   | Custom_Col2  
1    custom_val1     custom_val2

Variables Table
ID  |  Name       |  Value
1      var_name1     var_value1
2      var_name2     var_value2
3      var_name3     var_value3
4      var_name4     var_value4
5      var_name5     var_value5
6      var_name6     var_value6

```
{"Custom_Col1":"custom_val1", "Custom_Col2":"custom_val2","variables":{"var_name1":"var_value1","var_name2":"var_value2","var_name3":"var_value3", "var_name4":"var_value4","var_name5":"var_value5","var_name6":"var_value6"}}
```

I was able to get the looped values in by using the following, but I just don't know how to get the other variables in. I'm sure it's simple, I've just never worked with JSON before. I've scoured the internet and have found examples, but they have only gotten me so far:

```
var json = {}
while loop
{
 json[name]= value.toString();
}
var stringJson = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a collection in the same way you did with the var json.

```
var json = {}
while loopMasterTable
{
    json[name]= value.toString();
}
json['variables'] = {}
while loopVariableTable
{
    json['variables'][name]= value.toString();
}
var stringJson = JSON.stringify(json);
```

This will give you the following JSON:

```
{
    "Custom_Col1": "custom_val1",
    "Custom_Col2": "custom_val2",
    "variables": {
        "var_name1": "var_value1",
        "var_name2": "var_value2",
        "var_name3": "var_value3",
        "var_name4": "var_value4",
        "var_name5": "var_value5",
        "var_name6": "var_value6"
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was probably something simple. I'll give it a try!

Comment: The only thing I had to do was decalare json["variables"] = {}; at first because I was getting an undefined error, but other than that it worked like a charm.  Thank you!